# Where is the refreshToken endpoint implementation?

Tags: spring, jwt

I am using [springboot-security-jwt](https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt) because have good recomendation, and it is running... But when I was testing *refreshToken*, where the implementation?  How to use it?

Perhaps it is so obvious for a "Senior Developer Spring", but it is not for me, I not see it there. **Where the `/auth/token` endpoint implementation?**

There are some examples or documentation about it and how to (parameters) call it?

... Where the [springboot-security-jwt](https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt) `/token` endpoint implementation? to check it (or a kind of "health endpoint test")...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary configuration in the project springboot-security-jwt is in the WebSecurityConfig.java: (see https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/svlada/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.java).

In this class you will see a bean created of type AjaxLoginProcessingFilter configured with to intercept requests matching "/api/auth/login".  This will process the login and generate the JWT tokens.

You can then follow to the next bean configured - JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter to see what it is intercepting and authenticating using the JWTToken provided on the api requests

refreshToken is a standard spring controller - see RefreshTokenEndpoint class (https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/svlada/security/endpoint/RefreshTokenEndpoint.java)

The author also provides a detailed explanation in the Blog.md under the etc folder - check it out! there are lots of useful links to get up to speed on using JWTs